# How to fix Inconsistent Naming in Resharper Command Line Tools?

Tags: c#, resharper

When using Resharper Command Line Tools (see [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/ReSharper_Command_Line_Tools.html)), the CleanupCode routine fixes a lot of formatting issues, however, it does not fix Inconsistent Naming. It is then highlighted through Inspect Code, but not fixed automatically.

Inspect code usually will return something like this (in XML):

```html
      <Issue TypeId="InconsistentNaming" File="file.cs" Offset="26821-26835" Line="553" Message="Name 'FooBar' does not match rule 'Local variables'. Suggested name is 'fooBar'." />
```

Is there a way to get CleanupCode.exe to fix these according to coding style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `Cleanup Code` feature in ReSharper does not provide an automatic fix for the `Inconsistent Naming` inspection, the `CleanupCode.exe` tool can't fix it either.